# Python, Keras - Binary text classifier prediction results in array of values instead of single probability

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nlp, tf-idf

I am building a very simple DNN binary model which I define as:

```
def __build_model(self, vocabulary_size):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Embedding(vocabulary_size, 12, input_length=vocabulary_size))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])
    return model
```

with training like:

```
def __train_model(self, model, model_data, training_data, labels):
    hist = model.fit(training_data, labels, epochs=20, verbose=True, validation_split=0.2)

    model.save('models/' + model_data['Key'] + '.h5')

    return model
```

The idea is to feed tfidf vectorized text after training and predict whenever it belongs to class 1 or 0. Sadly when I run predict against it, I get an array of predictions instead of expected 1 probability for the article belonging to class 1. The array values seem very uniform. I assume this comes from some mistake in the model. I try popping prediction like so:

```
            self._tokenizer.fit_on_texts(asset_article_data.content)

            predicted_post_vector = self._tokenizer.texts_to_matrix(post, mode='tfidf')

            return model.predict(predicted_post_vector) > 0.60 // here return array instead of true/false
```

The training data is vectorized text itself. What might be off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake you are probably making is that the `post` is a string, whereas it should be a list of strings. That's why, as you mentioned, the `model.predict()` produces a lot of values: because tokenizer has iterated over the characters of `post` and produced a Tf-idf vector for each of them! Just put it in a list and the problem would be resolved:

```
... = self._tokenizer.texts_to_matrix([post], ...)
```

Comment: Looks like this was the issue, I get a single prediction after wrapping it around in an array. Pretty annoying and difficult to spot issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Keras is build to predict output for more than one input that's why the output is an array. Refer to the keras doc [here](https://keras.io/models/model/) (Returns Numpy array(s) of predictions). So if you need a single output, just select the first element of the array :

```
model.predict(predicted_post_vector)[0] > 0.60
```

Comment: I have a similar set of instructions which yield 1 probability but when I encapsulated them inside of a class I started getting the array, I went through all of the instructions one by one and see its exactly the same though so I think it's something with the code.

Comment: Nope, predict classes gives a class instead of a probability but its still an array of values instead of a single prediction as expected

Comment: I edited my answer. However could you specify what predicted_post_vector is and be more clear on what is your expected ouput.

Comment: It's specified, predicted_post_vector is just an article vectorized with tfIdf tokenizer from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer and the output should just be a single prediction. The answer with [0] is not right since I am expecting one output since I am feeding 1 record with features

Comment: That is not true. Keras doc says : Returns Numpy array(s) of predictions. So you will have a numpy arrays as output no matter the dimension of your input

Comment: Simon.. maybe I haven't been precise enough, it might return an array but in this case I expect an array with 1 value not 9000 uniform values that look all alike. Please see my comment on @Rubens_Zimbres post, might be the tokenizer not keras.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of solving your issue:

`model.predict_classes` as Simon said or use `argmax`

`np.argmax(model.predict(predicted_post_vector), axis=1)`

I would personally use `pd.get_dummies(y_train)` in your target variable and adjust output layer to `Dense(2, activation='sigmoid')`.

Comment: Thanks, it's the same as the asnwer from Simon, sadly it shouldn't be an array at all, selecting just the highest prediction is cheating that doesn't say much. I looked through the code and it seems the tokenizer is giving back a huge matrix of 0's instead of the expected row with word vectors, I am guessing the issue might be on the side of the tokenizer being fitted incorrectly (it should be fitted on the same data though as trained). Will check that.